# NetLogo: histogram relative frequency

Tags: histogram, netlogo, frequency-distribution

I'm still having problems with `[histogram]`.

I have a global variable (age-sick) that stores the age of the turtles when they got sick...and I want to plot the distribution: `histogram age-sick`

However I do **not** want the **absolute number** of turtles who got sick per every age, rather the **relative one**.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What you mean, “the relative one”? Can you explain it more?

Comment: Suppose I have this list: (1112345555)...the `histogram` function plots 5 bars: the first of height 3, the second, third and fourth of height 1 and the last of height 4.  Instead I want the first bar to be 30%, the second, third and fourth 10% and the last 40%...is there a way?

Comment: How is that materially any different? The heights end up the same, proportionally.

Comment: I get your point...but on the same plot I want two histograms...the age distribution when agents got sick and the actual age distribution of the agents...this is the reason why I want to normalize everything between 0 and 1000 (or 100)

Comment: I see. Then the `histogram` primitive won't help you; you'll have to roll your own. It's a bit sad that you can't reuse the underlying binning functionality of `histogram`; see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/367

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to overcome the problem in the following way:​​

```
let age-freq (list)
let i 0
while [ i <= (max age-sick)] [
let a filter [? = i] age-sick
repeat (length a / length age-sick * 1000) [set age-freq lput i age-freq]
set i i + 1]
histogram age-freq]
```